# GetPixel after SetPixel gives incorrect result

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I set pixel from one jpg. Save it another jpg file. Read a new file again. Get pixel. But it gives me incorrect result. 
That's my code:

```
use Image::Magick;
use Data::Dumper;

my $im = new Image::Magick;
$im->Read('file1.jpg');
my @pixel = $im->GetPixel(x=>0,y=>0,channel=>'RGB', normalize=>'True');
print Dumper(@pixel);

my @color = ('1.0', '0.0', '0.0');
$im->SetPixel(x=>0, y=>0, channel=>'RGB', normalize=>'True', color => \@color);
$im->Write('file30.jpg');

@pixel = $im->GetPixel(x=>0,y=>0,channel=>'RGB', normalize=>'True');
print Dumper(@pixel);

print "-" x 30, "\n";
my $nim = new Image::Magick;
$nim->Read('file30.jpg');

my @npixel = $nim->GetPixel(x=>0,y=>0,channel=>'RGB', normalize=>'True');
print Dumper(@npixel);
```

when I run it:

```
$VAR1 = '0.133333333333333';
$VAR2 = '0.141176470588235';
$VAR3 = '0.0588235294117647';
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '0';
$VAR3 = '0';
------------------------------
$VAR1 = '0.32156862745098';
$VAR2 = '0.247058823529412';
$VAR3 = '0.188235294117647';
```

Why @npixel gives me wrong result? How can it be fixed?

**UPD**

It works fine with .BMP files.

Comment: Is the result any different when using BITMAP images? They are raw data files, which employ no compression at all. A JPEG employs lossy compression, and your image may be undergoing a recompression stage when you save it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. All works for .bmp but is it possible to do the same thing with .jpg files?

Comment: Not if you want pixel-for-pixel perfection, because of the lossy compression.

What's your actual use case? Over the image as a whole what you're doing will broadly work, you can iterate through and set every pixel in the new image and get a copy of the original (for what that's worth), but you can't guarantee any individual pixel will match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting an answer to correspond to my comment above.

This would be best explained by a comparison of lossy vs lossless compression:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression

In short, you can work with an array of RGB pixels with imagemagick, set pixel values, get them, etc.

When you save, there are additional operations that are out of your control. In the case of JPEG, it is a lossy compression algorithm known as DCT (discrete cosine transformation): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform. This lossy compression (in the case of JPEG) is necessary in order to reduce the file size.

If you do not want to encounter this issue, you either need to work with:

1. Uncompressed data (ie: RAW/BMP files). When you save the file, it is written as-is to an output file. No compression or distortion is applied. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format
2. Use lossless compression. This typically compresses the data to reduce the file size, but does not shrink the file size as much as lossy compression does. PNG is an example of this, and ImageMagick supports it. Your data is NOT written as-is to the output file, but it is translated when saving and opening so you get all the original data back for every pixel exactly. 
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics